# Вывод из бд без setInterval (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


    function funcSuccess(data){
    $("#messages").html (data);
    };


    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax ({
                url: "message.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({
                    id: $("#id").val()
                    }),
                dataType: "html",
                success: funcSuccess
            });
        }, 100);
    });


</script>

<input type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Это код обращается к базе и выводит от туда все сообщений каждые 100ms.
Интервал нужен, чтобы выводить сообщение сразу после их появления в базе.
как можно обойтись без интервала?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас интересует технология под названием `websockets`. Создаете соединение с сервером, подписываетесь на событие onmessage. Когда ваш сервер запишет что-то в базу, он должен сообщить по вебсокету об этом всем подписанным браузерам. Это более щадящий способ, чем дергать какой-то скрипт 10 раз в секунду.

Код примерно такой ([из enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14112847/1023794)):

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://example.org:12345/myapp');

connection.onopen = function(){
   console.log('Connection open!');
}

connection.onclose = function(){
   console.log('Connection closed');
}

connection.onmessage = function(e){
   var server_message = e.data;
   console.log(server_message);
}
```

Остальное [в гайде](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/). Помните, что вебсокеты поддерживаются браузерами [начиная с IE10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).

Comment: только там php :)